# How to return JSON without re-serialization in ServiceStack service?

Tags: servicestack

In my service implemented in ServiceStack I already have response object serialized to JSON string. How can I return it without being serialized as a string? I would like to avoid   deserializing it into DTO instance only to be serialized back by ServiceStack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a snippet where I load a json file off disc:

```
 if (File.Exists(jsonFileLocation))
        {
            return new HttpResult(new FileInfo(jsonFileLocation), asAttachment: false,
                                  contentType: ContentType.Json);
        }
```